# I want one backslash - not two

Tags: python, string, backslash

I have a string that after print is like this: `\x4d\xff\xfd\x00\x02\x8f\x0e\x80\x66\x48\x71`

But I want to change this string to `"\x4d\xff\xfd\x00\x02\x8f\x0e\x80\x66\x48\x71"` which is not printable (it is necessary to write to serial port). I know that it ist problem with '`\`'. how can I replace this printable backslashes to unprintable?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to convert a string `'\\x4d\\x4e'` into `'\x4d\x4e'` (i.e. `'MN'`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to decode your string, use [`decode()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_decode.htm) with [`'string_escape'`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) as parameter which will interpret the literals in your variable as python literal string (as if it were typed as constant string in your code).

```
mystr.decode('string_escape')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `decode()`:

```
>>> st = r'\x4d\xff\xfd\x00\x02\x8f\x0e\x80\x66\x48\x71'
>>> print st
\x4d\xff\xfd\x00\x02\x8f\x0e\x80\x66\x48\x71
>>> print st.decode('string-escape')
MÿýfHq
```

That last garbage is what my Python prints when trying to print your unprintable string.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the printable representation of a string literal with the string itself:

```
>>> c = '\x4d\xff\xfd\x00\x02\x8f\x0e\x80\x66\x48\x71'
>>> c
'M\xff\xfd\x00\x02\x8f\x0e\x80fHq'
>>> len(c)
11
>>> len('\x4d\xff\xfd\x00\x02\x8f\x0e\x80\x66\x48\x71')
11
>>> len(r'\x4d\xff\xfd\x00\x02\x8f\x0e\x80\x66\x48\x71')
44
```

Answer (score 1):

```
your_string.decode('string_escape')
```

Comment: Thx! It is he solution of my problem

Comment: No idea, maybe because I included a link? We were all within a minute or so ;-) (honestly: I found some others clearer than mine, and quality, not speed, should warrant a checked answer).